# Setting up a subdomain for an already existing subfolder

Tags: htaccess, redirects, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subfolder won't permenantly redirect to subdomain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16420/subfolder-wont-permenantly-redirect-to-subdomain)

I have a forum installed in a subdirectory (http://www.example.com/forums/), but I want to have it accessed through forums.example.com and all traffic from the subdirectory passed to the subdomain.

From what I can read online this is a little bit harder since the subdirectory and subdomain would be the same name. I'm on a shared server so I can't setup the subdomain outside the root folder and ideally I want to still have it setup so other scripts I use outside of the forums can access the /forums/ subfolder (i.e. DOCUMENT_ROOT using PHP).

I'm not well versed at all in this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your shared web host provide access to a cPanel control panel or similar?

Comment: Umm, this isn't a duplicate of my other question. This is for an existing folder, which I've runs into issues if a subdomain is added onto it after it already exists.