# Subfolder won't permenantly redirect to subdomain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

Right now I have the following code to redirect all non-www URLs to www URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Besides that redirection, I also want to redirect all calls to /dev/ to dev.example.com. I've tried a bunch of different approaches but nothing has worked (the few that get close like ReplaceMatch will only redirect to the dev.example.com bit and will leave the rest as a query string).

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the full .htaccess for the root folder (a few rewritten for privacy reasons):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .json
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# disables image hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search\?q=cache [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]

# Stop htaccess rules from accessing these areas of the website.
RewriteRule ^(banner|boxart|cgi-bin|content|forums|includes|newsimages|newsimg|sidebar|union-files|google5e645385256c3a63.html) - [L]

# Redirects /page URLs to /page/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect old URLs to their new URLs
RewriteRule ^reviews/badurl--43.html$ http://www.gamingunion.net/reviews/goodurl--43.html [R=301,NC]

# Redirect non-WWW to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dev/(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/$1

# URL Directory Redirects
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?p=$1&urltype=slash [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?p=$1&urltype=slash [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?p=$1&lv1d=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?p=$1&lv1d=$2&lv2d=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?p=$1&lv1d=$2&lv2d=$3&lv3d=$4 [L,QSA]

# URL File Redirects
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&urltype=dot [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&lv1p=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&lv1d=$2&lv2p=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&lv1d=$2&lv2d=$3&lv3p=$4 [L,QSA]

# For servers that support output compression, you should pick up a bit of speed but un-commenting the following lines.
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

The one in /dev/ is basically the same as this one, except that it has a password protection bit at the top and has a few redirects for some image folders that only reside on the root of the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So .. you have more than 1 .htaccess file: one in the root folder and one in `/dev` folder.

Where did you put rules from @Alex -- root or /dev .htaccess? Most likely in root. That is the reason why it did not worked.

Thing is -- if Apache sees rewrite rules in lower level folder, it will NOT execute them from parent folder UNLESS your lower level .htaccess has `RewriteOptions inherit` line: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Now, you have added the below code into the .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dev/(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/$1
```

This directive belongs to another module and gets executed anyway .. and it executes **after** mod_rewrite have already rewritten the URL. That's why you see **real** URLs after redirect.

The rule below should work -- just put it into your **/dev/.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dev/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

It tells Apache to redirect if:

- domain is not dev.example.com
- URL starts with `/dev/` (which will only happened if requested via main domain)

Comment: When I use that code I should have removed the RedirectMatch from the root, right? If so, adding the code you provided in the dev subfolder didn't do anything.

Comment: @Shawn I have updated my answer with new rules (I edited wrong file when tested these rules myself -- I edited main htaccess instead the one from sub folder). The changes are minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*) http://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: And if you comment the rules that redirect non-www to www?

Comment: If not, since you have the non-www to www redirect, try this one: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/dev/(.*)$ http://dev.example.com/$1`

Comment: That one works, but it causes a URL like `http://dev.example.com/ps3/?p=ps3&urltype=slash`. Is there something that can be modified in the RedirectMatch or is there some other area of the htaccess file that's affecting things? (I'll be heading to bed in a few minutes, so I won't be able to look at this again till tomorrow morning.)

Comment: I don't understand what it does.

Comment: `www.example.com/dev/ps3/` -> `http://dev.example.com/ps3/?p=ps3&urltype=slash` with that code. (Basically, it's redirecting but it's also showing the behind-the-scenes stuff I'm doing that should be hidden to the user.)

Comment: @Shawn Post your whole .htaccess contents here (update your question) -- looks like you have rules in wrong order (RedirectMatch executes **after** RewriteRules that's why you see real URLs instead of nice one).

Comment: .htaccess is added.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following redirect-code to rewrite any sub-domains to a URL-parameter:

```
# rewrite subdomain
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=116&company_name=%1$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`%1` is the regex-match for the subdomain;
`$1` consists of all other URL-params;

Play around with it, to redirect to a folder, like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Maybe it's how my current configuration is, but I got infinite redirect loops whenever I tried using that.